# how to find neighbor of node?

Tags: python-3.x, matlab, multidimensional-array, networkx

I have a adjacent matrix type int32, I want to put neighbor of node in another matrix how can I do that?

```
{adja=nx.adj_matrix(G)
for i in range(len(G)):
    neighber_of_node=neighbor1[i]
```

}

I actually want to convert this matlab code to python, Idont understand 
how to convert adjacency(neighber_of_node,neighber_of_node) in python:

```
{  for i=1:len(adjacency)
   neighber_of_node=neighbours[i,:];
  neighbor_of_neighbor=adjacency(neighber_of_node,neighber_of_node);}
```

Comment: Hello, Don. If you can take a few more minutes and explain your problem more clearly, with small examples of what you are trying to do, then more people will be able to help you.

Comment: I have 9 node in graph I want to find neighbor of each node and for each node find the neighbor that has **maximum** degree and keep all the maximum neighbor of all nodes in matrix, my problem is I cant define a loop that do this,my program only do this process for one node.I hope that I express  my meaning

Comment: You explanation above is quite helpful. You should add that to the problem above, tell us why the loop is failing. Also, if you can share your 9-node graph with some sample data, that makes it easier to help

Comment: this is my code that i run but I cant get good result, Thanks alot by the way

Comment: `''neighber_of_node={}`
       
`for i in range(len(AdjMatrix)):`
    
`a=np.array(AdjMatrix[:,i])`

`neighbor1[i]=np.where(a == 1)[0]`

""" find neighboer of all node i""" `
`for j in range(len(AdjMatrix)):`
    
`neighber_of_node=neighbor1[j]`

Comment: sorry the code is not clear, but my problem is that I cant set all neighbor of all node and kept in dict